# Issue with datetime "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I am using the code below to check the datetime and it is working fine in my machine but once after deployment, I am getting

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Please provide me the solution to work in all machine.

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse("16/05"); MM/dd
string todaydate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd");

if (Convert.ToDateTime(todaydate) > Convert.ToDateTime(date1.ToString("MM/dd")))
{  //Logic }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you converting your dates to strings and then right back to dates again?

Comment: Why are you taking a date, converting it to a string, and then converting it back to a date?

Comment: Use DateTime.TryParseExact. This method allows you to specify how you want the string to be parsed. Check it out here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So what would be the best suggestion from your point of view to work in any culture.do i need to use culture?

Comment: I think this is a culture settings issue.

Comment: What is the data source for your date strings?

Comment: @mason - actually, by default, the parse method will assume the current date and time components for anything not provided, such as year and time-of-day in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, since both answer didn't satisfied me, here is my [two cent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two_cents#Noun)..

Let's look at your code line by line;

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse("16/05");
```

[`DateTime.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse.aspx) uses your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) settings *by default* if don't provide any `IFormatProvider` as a second parameter on it's overloads. That means, if your one of [standard date and time patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your `CurrentCulture` includes `dd/MM` (or your current culture [`DateSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) since [`/` format separator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning of *replace me with current culture date separator*) format, this parsing operation will be successful. That means this line *might* throws `FormatException` that depends on the current culture settings.

```
string todaydate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd");
```

`DateTime.Now` returns a local current time. With it's `ToString()` method you try to get it's string representation with `MM/dd` format. BUT WAIT! You used `/` format specifier again and still, you didn't use any `IFormatProvider`. Since this format specifier replace itself with current culture date separator, your `todaydate` might be `05/16`, `05-16` or `05.16`. That's totally depends on what date separator your current culture use.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(todaydate)
```

`Convert.ToDateTime` method uses `DateTime.Parse` explicitly. That means,since you didn't provide any `IFormatProvider` it will be use your `CurrentCulture` again and it's standard date and time formats. As I said, `todaydate` might be `05/16`, `05-16` or `05.16` as a result. But **there is no guarantee** that your current culture parse this string successfully because it *may* not have `MM/dd` in it's standard date and time formats. If it parse `"16/05"` successfully, that means it has `dd/MM` format, in such a case, it definitely can't have `MM/dd` as a standard date and time format. A culture *can't* parse `dd/MM` and `MM/dd` formats at the same time. In such a case, it can't know that `01/02` string should parse as 2nd January or 1st February, right?

```
Convert.ToDateTime(date1.ToString("MM/dd"))
```

Same as here. As `todaydate` string, this will create `"05/16"` (it depends on current culture date separator of course) result and still there is no guarantee to parse this successfully.

And as said in comments, there is no point to parse your string to DateTime and get it's same string representation as well.

I strongly suspect you try to compare your current date is bigger than your parsed DateTime or not, you can use [`DateTime.Today` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to compare with it. This property gets DateTime as current date part plus midnight as time part. For example;

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact("16/05", "dd/MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
     if(DateTime.Today > dt)
     {
          // Your operation
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("16/05", "dd/MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
if (DateTime.Today > dt)
{
    // your application logic
}
```

Comment: Nice, but to be complete, you should show the comparison also.

Comment: @MattJohnson : help me out to complete this :)

Comment: _"Try the below code"_ - why? What does it do? Please explain what code you post as an answer does.

Comment: @MattJohnson : So do we need to format Datetime.Today ? i guess it will be dd/mm or mm/dd as per system.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry for "Try the below code". I should not use it.

Comment: @user1721131 - No, you do not need to format it.  It is a `DateTime`, not a `string`.  Its comparison is based on its internal number of ticks, not on any particular string representation.

Comment: @user1721131 - Also, you should be aware that `Today` will be of the time zone where the code is running - which might not necessarily be the time zone where the user is.

Comment: @MattJohnson : System.DateTime dt = System.DateTime.ParseExact("17/03", "dd/MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); this is giving me always 03/17/2015 after formatting.

Comment: No, it gives you a `DateTime`.  When you *format* the `DateTime` as a string, you are seeing it with the current culture applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = // From whatever source
if (DateTime.Now.Ticks > dt.Ticks)
{
    // Do logic
}
```